# I'm not able to run any flutter app on my emulator (VSC & Android Studio)

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

So basically the problem is that I created a new flutter app, and the I opened the emulator(from android studio), and I clicked on run.
I had multiple problems that were related to heap memory and such, but I managed to solved most of then using all kind of methods from the internet.
I even deleted and installed Java and android studio multiple times, I changed the Enviromental Variables as the Internet suggested, but now, the current error that I get is this:
[The Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64xFx.jpg)

my flutter doctor -v:

[flutter doctor -v image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Rgh4.png)

I'm about to lose my mind, I'm on this issuse for a few weeks. please help me fix it

after your seggestion to add "gradle.properties" and adding "org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m" to it (without the " "):
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZuGg.png)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you shoud add a line at end of file **gradle.properties** `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m` then clean the project, also validate cache and restart the android studio. It should works then.

Comment: I added the flutter doctor -v image

Comment: I have just modified the answer, you could check it if it works

Comment: I dont have the file "gradle.properties"

Comment: I added the picture when I added "gradle.properties", still an error